# Is there a way to run the DataStage jobs based on different dates?

Tags: datastage, ibm-information-server

I have a table containing the dates for the ETL jobs to be run.

I do know that using the schedule function in DataStage director able to schedule the jobs run on a specific date or recurring weekly/monthly. However, in my case, the date will change.

For example, Job A need to run every mid of Feb, May, and August.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One option could be a DataStage sequence that runs regularily (i.e. daily) checking if one of your run dates is reached. This could be checked within the sequence and if the condition is fulfilled run the job.

If you choose to try it you need a job which selects the dates tables - you could compare the date already in the SQL with the current date and then sendthe date to a file or any other flag. Read the file within the sequence and if your check condition is true run whatever job you need to run.